# Validating and invalidating session in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm developing an application wherein a user clicks on withdraw link and it should reach to withdraw page. I'm using session object to track the user.But the problem is when I copy paste the link generated with appended jsession id in different browser I'm still able to withdraw money. I know this is what happens when we use session object. Can you guys tell me how should I proceed if I want to invalidate the session id its from different browser ?

Comment: Why would you want that? If you pass the session id and the session is not close (and optionnaly you use same IP) the request **is** member of session. Do not use HTTP if you do not like that...

Comment: I agree with @SergeBallesta, other option would be to configure your servlet container or application server in order to not write the JSESSIONID in the request but always in a cookie; so when you change the browser.. the cookie is not present and you should not be able in withdrawing money